# Passing parameter from PrimeFaces datatable to managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="idCrawledDataTable"
    var="crawledData"
    value="#{crawlerCorpusTreatmentBean.crawledDataModel}"
    rowKey="#{crawledData.id}"
    rows="10"
    scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="300"
    selection="#{crawlerCorpusTreatmentBean.crawledData}"
    style="width: 850px;">

 <f:facet name="header">
     RadioButton Based Selection
 </f:facet>

  <p:column selectionMode="single"
     style="width: 12px;"/>

  <p:column headerText="id"
     style="width: 20px;">
         #{crawledData.id}
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Sritis"
      style="40px;">
          #{crawledData.domain}
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="URL"
      style="width: 450px;">
          #{crawledData.url}
  </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

It is all filled with values after action method is called. Datatable has radio button selection. When I select one of the radio button and click the command button, I go to some method in which I call my bean, but all values from datatable that my bean has is null.

Showcases shows only how to display data in modal window, I can not find any information on how to pass parameters to managed bean. Maybe someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works just for me. Perhaps your data loading logic is wrong (e.g. you're doing it inside a getter method) or the `equals()` method of the object behind `rowKey` is broken.

Here's a self-containing kickoff example so that you can at least nail down your own mistake:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item" selection="#{bean.item}" rowKey="#{item.id}">
        <p:column selectionMode="single" />
        <p:column headerText="id">#{item.id}</p:column>
        <p:column headerText="value">#{item.value}</p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> items;
    private Item item;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item(1L, "one"));
        items.add(new Item(2L, "two"));
        items.add(new Item(3L, "three"));
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(item);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

where `Item` has just `Long id` and `String value` properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved this issue in another way, not using dataTable, but in future I think this will help me. Thanks again.